# .NET Sandbox and Application Base

Tags: .net, security, sandbox

In the [Microsoft guidance for how to run partially trusted code in a sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx), it mentions

> For security reasons, the application base specified in the info parameter should not be the application base for the hosting application.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.  I found an example [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869951/can-an-appdomain-be-restricted-to-one-directory) that does use the the current application base.  I just found another [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280251/should-applicationbase-be-different-for-the-sandbox-appdomain) that seems to provide the explanation we're looking for.  I guess using the same base allows the slave AppDomain to exploit its parent.